# And we're public!

Tags: discussion

In case anyone missed it, we have now gone from our private beta to a public one.  From the email:

> After just 8 days in private beta, we've already got 158 users who have asked 222 questions and written 491 answers.

Great job, let's keep at it!

Comment: Nice one. This is the first SE site I've really participated in outside of SO, so it's good to see it take off well!

Answer (score 5):

Yeah its great news :) I'm using social networks and inviting others to join from other forums to try and get more people involved :)

Comment: Great! That's exactly what we need, more users asking and more experts answering.